# Why my struct returning from interface method not implements another interface in golang?

Tags: go, struct, interface, polymorphism

I have this code.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Monetary interface {
    GetDecimals() int64
}

type Account interface {
    GetBalance() Monetary
}

type balance struct {
    decimals int64
}

func (b *balance) GetDecimals() int64 {
    return 0
}

type account struct {
    b *balance
}

func (a *account) GetBalance() *balance {
    return a.b
}

func NewAccount() *account {
    return &account{
        b: &balance{},
    }
}

func main() {
    var acc Account = NewAccount()
    fmt.Println(acc)
}
```

Which returns me an error:

```
cannot use NewAccount() (value of type *account) as Account value in variable declaration: *account does not implement Account (wrong type for method GetBalance)
        have GetBalance() *balance
        want GetBalance() Monetary
```

But my `*balance` implement `Monetary` exactly. This code will no have any error:

```golang
func main() {
    acc := NewAccount()
    b := acc.GetBalance()
    m := (Monetary)(b)
    fmt.Println(acc, m)
}
```

Got error, but excepting no any error

Comment: To implement an interface the method's signature MUST match _verbatim_, i.e. its name MUST be the same, and its input parameter types and output parameter types MUST be __identical__. `GetBalance() *balance` != `GetBalance() Monetary`. See also: https://go.dev/doc/faq#t_and_equal_interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mkopriva said in a comment.

> to implement an interface the method's signature MUST match verbatim, i.e. its name MUST be the same, and its input parameter types and output parameter types MUST be identical.

Go very strict with typing.  Even though `*balance` implements `Monetary`, `func (*account) GetBalance() *balance` still doesn't satisfy `GetBalance() Monetary`.

The fix is simple.  Just change `account`'s `GetBalance` to return `Monetary` not `*balance`.

```
func (a *account) GetBalance() Monetary {
   ...
```

Since since `*balance` implements `Monetary`, `account.GetBalance` can return an `a.b`  *as* a `Monetary` interface holding `*balance`.